# Create a new list horizontally with a unique value in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, list

Suppose I have a data in Sheet1 Excel like this

```
C           D
ID-YEAR   LEVEL
1-2005      1
1-2006      2
1-2006      2
1-2006      1
1-2007      3
```

How can I make a table in Excel that list horizontally the unique value of level?
for example,

```
G           H            I
ID-YEAR   1stLevel    2ndLevel  
1-2005        1          0       
1-2006        2          1   
1-2007        3          0
```

I have tried using this formula

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6,SMALL(IF($G2=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6,ROW(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6)-1,""),1),COLUMNS($H$2:H2))
```

But it only shows the 1st level not all the of the level

Comment: You can do this using Power Query or VBA. Possibly with formulas. Since this is not a free code-writing service, please show what you have tried and where you have run into problems.

Comment: Of course I have tried using a formula. I have edited my question, if you know how to fix the problem, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using Power Query.
You have to refresh the Query when the data changes.

***Using Power Query***

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm and understand any limitations or modifications you may need to make.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],

/*Make Type text so as to avoid 
    automatic date translation in column 1
    be able to combine the levels in column 2*/

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID-YEAR", type text}, {"LEVEL", type text}}),

//Group by ID-YEAR, then extract the unique list of LEVEL for each year
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID-YEAR"}, {
        {"Level", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([LEVEL]),";")}
        }),

//Split the column that lists the Levels into multiple columns

/*Change the **2** at the end of the line to the maximum number of columns/levels
        If this will be dynamic, it can be computed*/

    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Level", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), 2)
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

***Note:** If you want to have `0` instead of `blanks` where there is no relevant level, in the PQ code, at the end, from the User Interface, you can*

- Select all the columns
- `Replace Values`  and replace `null` with `0`